# android convert from arrraylist of bitmaps to video and show it

Tags: android

the main problem now i want to ad effects on video
i got that idea to convert the video into bitmaps add effects then return it again 
but i cound`t return it to video again

any help
or any other way to do add effects on video without using ffmpeg

```
    public ArrayList<Bitmap> getFrames(Uri path) {
    try {
        bArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        bArray.clear();
        MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        // mRetriever. setDataSource(path);
        mRetriever.setDataSource(this, path);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            // time in msec 1000*i
            bArray.add(mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(10,
                    MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST));

        }
        return bArray;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to your getFrameatTime's first parameter that is in microsends. Otherwise you will still get the first frame's bitmap as return. Maybe your can decode the frames and show them in sequence like a movie.